# Insert value or select options value into database in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html select box, what I want is to insert the value of option

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
 <select name="myselectbox">
  <option value="myoption1"></option>
  <option value="myoption2"></option>
  <option value="myoption3"></option>
  <option value="myoption4"></option>
 </select>
<input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Into database, I clear this that the value which I want is the value of value attribute in option tag.

Comment: $selectedOption = $_POST['myselectbox']; then write your INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST['myselectbox']` to insert do db. It will be taken data from combo box.

Answer (score 0):

First Connect Database

```
 <form action='' method='post'>
     <select name="myselectbox">
         <option value="" hidden="hidden">Select Option</option>
         <?php
         $showoption = mysql_query("select * from tablename")or die(mysql_error());
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($showoption )){
              $optionid=$row['id'];
              $optionname=$row['name'];
              echo = "<option value='$optionid'>$optionname</option>";
           }
         }
         ?>
     </select>
     <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
 </form>
```

Comment: He wants to insert a value, this is selecting a value... Additionally, don't use `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` is depreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give the submit button a name in following way.

```
  <input type='submit' name="submit" value='submit'/>
```

Now try the following code.

```
    //First establishing a connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli("mysql_host", "mysql_user", "mysql_pass", "mysql_db");
    //checking if database connection is successful
    if($mysqli->connect_errno>0)
    {
        die("Connection to MySQL-server failed!"); 
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //ok, now we will prepare a query to insert the selected option value
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename(optionvalue) VALUES(?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['myselectbox']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```